# Can't submit a post request using Django rest framework ("detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.")

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am into a weird situation I am login into site and try to submit form if I use  `permission_classes = [AllowAny]`  or isAuthenticate  classes I get error  `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect`

And in following scenario it  gives a popup to enter password and user name . My full class is like

```
class AddReview(APIView):
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    def post(self, request):  
        rest = request.POST.get('restaurant')
        dish = request.POST.get('dish')
```

And my **settings.py**  is

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',

    ),
}
```

I just want to submit a post custom form to submit data. Any help or suggestion to make question good would be highly appericiated.

**Update**

I am able to submit form by using this

```
class SessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):
    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return
```

But why I have to enforce it ?  What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Use the "django cors headers" and check it. Google it, it is easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you website form should have a csrf token and that should also be sent to server. Maybe something like :

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}</form>
```

1. The CSRF middleware is activated by default in the `MIDDLEWARE` setting.
2. If you want to disable CSRF protection just a few views use `csrf_exempt()` decorator

---

**References**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: Everything is same as you mentioned . I have included token. When I submit form I get a anonymous user If I dont include    " authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,) "  before function of post  In this case I get a authentication popup in chrome.

Comment: What is the response code and headers ?
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#unauthorized-and-forbidden-responses

Comment: removed authentication classes from view   then I am getting this  = >>        HTTP 403 Forbidden
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}

Comment: if I add  authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)    it asks username and password in popup

Comment: I think BasicAuthentication is for API, for web pages session should work - or you'll need to explore more on this